# simple jquery animate not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a simple background image that's moving continously left to right. works great in all browsers except firefox (tested just 11);

this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        animateClouds();                                
    });

    function animateClouds() {
        $('#theclouds').animate ({
            'background-position-x': '+=5000'
        }, 100000, 'linear', function() {
            animateClouds();            
      });
    }
```

Comment: Firefox not support `background-position-x` CSS property

Comment: As an aside, you'd be better off animating this using `setInterval`. What happens if someone stays on your page for longer than 1:40 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `background-position-x` property in the CSS spec.  Some browsers support it anyway; Firefox happens not to.

Answer (score 1):

Using this will solve this problem. I've used it myself and it works great:

https://github.com/Poetro/jQuery.backgroundPosition