# jquery animate function getting freezed in mozilla

Tags: jquery-1.8

I am using animate function to scroll left and right based on user selection, in other browsers like safari, chrome and ie works properly but in mozilla for some margins like -300% or -100% the browser getting freezed to check issue below is the link check for php or css metro buttons.

jquery version: 1.8.1.min.js

browser version = 21.0

http://www.momeen.com

Answer (score 0):

Try the other questions about this problem:

- [jquery Animate() not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601069/jquery-animate-not-working-in-firefox)
- [jQuery Animate on Background not working in FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539575/jquery-animate-on-background-not-working-in-firefox)
- [simple jquery animate not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963352/simple-jquery-animate-not-working-in-firefox)
- https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit/issues/92

I don't have your code but a common problem is:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

Good luck!

Comment: below is my code which is freezing for firefox 1366 * 768 resolution
http://pastebin.com/R9hDGLQd